# How should a WCF service implementation handle errors/faults without coupling to FaultContract

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, soap

I understand the concept of Fault Contracts in WCF, but they seem to be tightly coupled to WCF and SOAP in particular.  I've created a set of services that are separate from the contract definitions and the implementations could be used in many ways, not just WCF/SOAP.  For instance, if I wanted to create a RESTful service, or just use the services implementation directly from an application.

But now I'm working on error handling and it seems that as soon as I introduce FaultContract and FaultException into the service code, I'm now tightly bound to SOAP services.  In my case, SOAP is the target wire format right now, and so I want to produce a SOAP fault.

What methods are people using in WCF to produce SOAP faults, but not couple the implementation to FaultContract?

Comment: SOAP is SOAP is SOAP - why wouldn't you use **SOAP** exceptions in your **SOAP** services?? ....

Comment: I know it seems weird.  But, in case I want to support other wire formats with the same implementation, I'm separating contracts and wire format from the implementation of the service.  In my implementation I have nothing SOAP specific, and nothing WCF specific.  But, I'm producing SOAP messages through the WCF config and contracts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For decoupling error handling from your service implementation, have your service implement IErrorHandler. This allows you to throw standard .NET exceptions in your service code. The IErrorHandler behavior translates them to SOAP faults at the service level.

There's lots of examples on the web. The one I like most is [here](http://dotnetslackers.com/wcf/re-145510_wcf_ierrorhandler_and_propagating_faults.aspx) because I actually made the same mistake with fault actions that he points how to fix.

Comment: Yes, IErrorHandler looks like the key.  Thanks for the link.  Here's another good guide: http://www.olegsych.com/2008/07/simplifying-wcf-using-exceptions-as-faults/

Answer (score 3):

Use FaultContract in operations if you want to throw expected exception. You will get some small set of FaultContracts used in your operations. When you need to add non SOAP endpoint you can use [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) implementation in custom endpoint behavior and convert thrown FaultExceptions to format you need. [Here](http://zamd.net/2008/07/08/error-handling-with-webhttpbinding-for-ajaxjson/) you have some example for JSON.

Comment: Thanks. I agree IErrorHanler is the key, and I gave @ErnieL the accepted answer because he was first.  I also prefer the idea of keeping FaultContract completely out of the implementation and convert from .NET Exception to FaultContract in the IErrorHandler code.