# Throwing FaultException<T> from WCF service methods

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, fault, faultexception

I am learning WCF, and currently focusing on the Faults chapter.

As i understand, WCF handles FaultException exceptions a bit differently when thrown by a service.

As such, it seems like a good idea that all exceptions that are thrown from a service should be wrapped into a FaultException.

Design wise it seems a bit counter-intuitive for me with respect to the design that WCF seems to favor (a clean separation between the actual logic and the "service" configuration/hosting/service-like details).

Is this a good practice then? or is there any other technique that should be used?

Comment: What you are really asking is:
[How should a WCF service implementation handle errors/faults without coupling to FaultContract][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789556/how-should-a-wcf-service-implementation-handle-errors-faults-without-coupling-to

Answer (score 1):

It is common practice to set up a `FaultContract` on your WCF service, which defines how it is has failed, and then handle this at the client side.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733721.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/01/14/wcf-spike-faultcontract-faultexception-lt-tdetail-gt-and-validation.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on following:

- [WCF error handling and some best practices](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2008/01/25/wcf-error-handling-and-some-best-practices.aspx)
- [Exception Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949036.aspx)
- [Avoid Exceptions in Faults](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2008/05/20/avoid-exceptions-in-faults.aspx)